# NullPointerException using Page Object Model in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, nullpointerexception, pageobjects

I'm currently trying to revamp my Selenium test cases by implement the Page Object Model in them.  However, the website I'm testing deals with a lot of modals.  When I try to access certain modals, I get a NullPointerException.  I can't tell if the driver isn't waiting for the element or what.

Here are my classes:

**Page Object**

```
public class ManualShipmentModal
{
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverWait wait;

@FindBy(id = "manual-order-modal")
WebElement modalBody;

@FindBy(name = "mailToName")
WebElement toName;

/* Constructor */
public ManualShipmentModal(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 100);
    PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
}

public boolean modalExists()
{
    return modalBody.isDisplayed();
}

public void enterToAddress(String toName, String addressName)
{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(modalBody));
    WebElement toAddress = driver.findElement(By.linkText(addressName));

    this.toName.sendKeys(toName);
    toAddress.click();
}
```

}

**Test class**

```
public class TEST_11
{

WebDriver driver;

LoginPage loginPageObj;
HeaderMenu headerMenuObj;
ManualShipmentModal manualShipmentModalObj;

@Before
public void setup()
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("testpage.com");
}

@Test
public void testCreateNewShipment()
{
    loginPageObj = new LoginPage(driver);
    headerMenuObj = new HeaderMenu(driver);
    manualShipmentModalObj = new ManualShipmentModal(driver);

    loginPageObj.login("username", "password");
    headerMenuObj.createNewShipment();
    manualShipmentModalObj.enterToAddress("Test", "The Usual Test");
}

@After
public void teardown()
{
    driver.close();
}
}
```

It runs fine up until I call enterToAddress().  When it gets to that point, it throws a NullPointerException.  It seems like the driver isn't waiting for the element to load even though I have an implicit wait defined as well as an explicit wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebDriverWait wait` isn't instantiated, so calling it throws a `NullPointerException`.

Use its constructor in `ManualShipmentModal`'s constructor:

```
public ManualShipmentModal(WebDriver driver)
{
    this.driver = driver;
    long timeOutInSeconds = 10; // just an arbitrary value example
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds);

    // the rest of your constructor as in the original code
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    AjaxElementLocatorFactory factory = new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, 100);
    PageFactory.initElements(factory, this);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow... Now I feel embarrassed.  Thank you for the pointer!!